# MIMEMultipart() in Python

Tags: python

Why do I always get `From nobody` when creating a message with `MIMEMultipart()` in Python? Is this changeable?

```
msg2 = MIMEMultipart('csv')                                                                                                                      
print msg2                                                                                                                                       
From nobody Mon Feb 29 11:38:50 2016                                                                                                                  
Content-Type: multipart/csv; boundary="===============3465836505230217811=="                                                                          
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to whatever you want by using [`set_unixfrom`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.set_unixfrom):

```
>>> from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
>>> msg = MIMEMultipart('csv')
>>> msg.set_unixfrom('From user')
>>> print msg
From user
Content-Type: multipart/csv; boundary="===============9221413516749323109=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

`From nobody` is [hardcoded value](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/email/generator.py#L113) if `unixfrom` is not set for a given message.